# how to echo/show result in the search datatables?

Tags: javascript, datatables

I have created a javascript code which combine 3 input type text.
but how can I show the value in search datatables? 
see this: [image]

this the script where I combine 3 input type.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$(".form-control").change(function(){
    $("#filter").val($("#text_1-1").val() + " " + $("#text_1-2").val()+ " " +$("#text_1-22").val());

    var values = "";

    $("sas").each(function(i) {
        values += (i > 0 ? "\n" : "") + this.value;
    });
    $("textarea").val(values);

});

});//]]> 
</script>

 <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2" for="name" >First Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text_1-1" name="fname" placeholder="" style="text-transform: capitalize;" required>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Middle Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2"> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text_1-2" name="mname" value="" style="text-transform: capitalize;" placeholder="">
    </div>
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Last Name:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-2"> 
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="text_1-22" name="lname"  style="text-transform: capitalize;" placeholder="" required>
    </div>
  </div>
```

then the combination will be paste it here: (but how it will go to the search datatables?)

```
   <input type="text" class="form-control" class="sas" id="filter"  style="text-transform: capitalize;" placeholder="" required>
```

here's my datatables approach:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="media/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="media/css/jquery.dataTables_themeroller">
<script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="media/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#datatables').dataTable({
        "scrollY":        "300px",
        "scrollCollapse": true,
        "paging":         false
    });
});
</script>
<title>Datatable</title>
</head>
<body>
<table id="datatables" class="display">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>first name</th>
        <th>middle name</th>
        <th>last name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['fname']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['mname']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['lname']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

purpose: this system will automatically search names in the datatables when filling up the input type (fname,mname,lname)

Comment: Please show your datatables initialisation code.

Comment: @markpsmith I added it. hope you can help me. thank you

Comment: Are you sure that's the right table? The column headings are completely different

Comment: @markpsmith edited. please have a check.

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use [`search()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/search%28%29) API method.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable();

$(".form-control").on('keyup change', function () {
    var query = $("#text_1-1").val() + " " + $("#text_1-2").val() + " " + $("#text_1-22").val();

    table.search(query).draw(false);
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3d0wzvr9/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: @kimdecastro, make sure you're using `DataTables()` not `dataTables()` to initialize your code to use `table.search(query).draw(false);`. Otherwise, you can use `$('#example').DataTable().search(query).draw(false);` to search where `example` is your table ID.